# Does induction find all solutions?

Tags: induction, functional-equations

Induction shows that an equality holds for all values of $n$. It doesn't show that this is the only equality or formula for the expression that may hold true, correct? For example, say a question asks to find an explicit formula for a functional equation given by $f(n) = f(f(n-1))+f(n-f(n-1))$ for $n > 1$. You can prove by induction that $f(n) = n$ is indeed an explicit expression for $f(n)$, but it may not be the only one? If so, what steps must be taken to prove that it is the only one?

Edit: Sorry, I meant to point out that $f(1) = 1$

Comment: Could you post a the proof by induction that you're thinking of? I would imagine that it is a proof that there is only one solution - because you don't need induction to prove that $f(n)=n$ is a solution; you just substitute it in.

Comment: f(x) = 0 is also a solution.

Comment: To prove by induction is quite simple. You just assume it is true for some $k$ and then use the RHS expression for $k+1$ to show that it eventually simplifies to $k+1$.

Comment: @martycohen are you sure?

Comment: In this case $n > 1$.

Comment: @user19405892: 0 = 0+0.

Comment: @martycohen See the edit, which added an initial condition.

Comment: That always annoys me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction proves . . . whatever it proves. For instance:

- We might use an induction argument to show that some $f$ is a solution to a functional equation $E$. In the absence of any other arguments, this won't say that $f$ is the *unique* solution.
- On the other hand, we might use induction to show that $f$ is the *unique* solution to a functional equation $E$. For a silly example, if $E$ is $$f(n+1)=f(n)+1,$$ we can prove by induction that every solution $f$ to $E$ is of the form $f(x)=x+c$ for some fixed $c$. (Specifically, we would argue: let $f$ satisfy $E$, and set $c=f(0)$. Then by induction on $n$, we can show $f(n)=n+c$. So every solution to $E$ has this form.)

---

EDIT: in the specific case you're interested in, we can indeed use induction to prove that $f(n)=n$ is the only solution. There's a few ways to phrase it, but here's one which is general enough to be useful in other contexts:

- We have an initial value, $f(1)=1$. (I'm assuming your natural numbers start with 1, not 0.)
- *Informally*: In the functional equation, each value of $f(n)$ (for $n>1$) is determined by the values of $f$ on numbers $<n$.
- *Formally*: By induction, we can show that if $f$ and $g$ are two solutions to the functional equation and $f(1)=g(1)$, then $f(n)=g(n)$ for every $n$; that is, $f=g$. (This is a good exercise.)
- So there is a unique solution.

Comment: Is it necessary to prove that this is the only solution for the purpose of this question or just proving by induction that it is a solution is okay?

Comment: I think the point of this answer is that there is nothing inherent in inductiom vs. any other type of proof that makes it better or worse in whether it proves a solution is sufficient or whether it is unique.

Answer (score 1):

$f(n) = f(f(n-1))+f(n-f(n-1))
$

If $f(n) = an+b$,

$\begin{array}\\
an+b
&=f(a(n-1+b))+f(n-(a(n-1)+b))\\
&=a((a(n-1)+b))+b+a(n-(a(n-1)+b))+b\\
&=a(an-a+b)+2b+a(n-(an-a)-b))\\
&=a^2n-a^2+ab+2b+an-a^2n+a^2-ab\\
&=an+ab+2b-ab\\
&=an+2b\\
\end{array}
$

so $b=0$,
and
$f(n) = an$
for any $a$ is a solution.

Comment: Note that while this works for the OP's original question, their edit - adding the initial condition "$f(1)=1$" - changes things.